# Uploading image to Firebase: Null pointer Exception(bitmap.compress)

Tags: android, firebase, android-bitmap, firebase-storage

Since [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files) documentation is not for begginers, sometimes it can be hard and complex for beginners.

I want to upload image to storage of firebase. I read their documentation and tried but it gives **NullPointerException**.

I think this null pointer exception is about imageview. There is a **abc.jpg** image in the drawable folder.

There is no maintains.jpg file on the firebase side. Should there be maintains.jpg file on the firebase? I couldn't also understand [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/create-reference)

Activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="gc.imageuploader.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/abc"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

        // Create a storage reference from our app
        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("(Mybucketnamehere)");

        StorageReference mountainsRef = storageRef.child("mountains.jpg");

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);




        imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        imageView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);//Error line
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

        UploadTask uploadTask = mountainsRef.putBytes(data);
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        });
}
```

Finally, How to solve?

Comment: `imageView.getDrawingCache();` can return `null`. Which it does.

Comment: Sorry for error line, one previous line is error line. I am editing now.

Comment: So what is the solution? What should I do?

Comment: ??? Did you edit? What is the code that causes the NullPointerException?

Comment: bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); This line. Also, imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); this line is yellow "may produce nullpointer exception"

Comment: http://i.hizliresim.com/3AydP4.png

Comment: `bitmap==null`. Check before use.

Comment: It is working now(I mean no compiler error but not uploading), but if bitmap is null How can I upload ?

Comment: Somebody else had the same problem as you. Today or yesterday on this firum. So lok around a bit.